# activemq UDP jms connection

Tags: udp, jms

i work on a project with activemq java and i use ssl or udp connection .To receive messqge i use a QeueueReceiver and MessageListener Classes .the problem is that the ssl connection perfectly but when i choose  a udp connection and i send 7 messages and i put the listener working i receive 5 messages after i receive only 2 messages . i DONT know what exactly the problem sombedoy can help please there is a code

code
ry {
            switch (protocol) {
            case "UDP":
                connectionFactoryUDP = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrlUDP);
                connection = connectionFactoryUDP.createQueueConnection(username, password);

```
            break;
        case "TLS":

            connectionFactoryTLS = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
            // create connection

            connectionFactoryTLS.setBrokerURL(brokerUrlTLS);
            connectionFactoryTLS.setTrustStore(trustStore);
            connectionFactoryTLS.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
            connectionFactoryTLS.setKeyStore(keyStore);
            connectionFactoryTLS.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
            connection = connectionFactoryTLS.createQueueConnection(username,password);


            break;}


        //ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.username, this.password, "tcp://localhost:61616");
        // create connection


        // start


        connection.start();

        // create session


        // create queue (it will create if queue doesn't exist)

        // create listener
        System.out.println("____________________________________");

        MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                System.out.println("____________________________________");
                // only text type message
                if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                    TextMessage txt = (TextMessage) message;
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Message received =---_________--" + txt.getText());
                    } catch (JMSException e) {
                        System.out.println("error retrieving message");
                        System.exit(1);
                    }
                }

            }
        };

        session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
        QueueReceiver consumer = session.createReceiver(queue);
        consumer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
        System.in.read();
        consumer.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("-----------closed----------");
```

log console
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG UdpTransport:382 - Binding to address: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:0
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:55 - SENDING: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-1:1, clientId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-0:1, clientIp = null, userName = aymenmhidhi, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = false, failoverReconnect = false}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG UdpTransport:124 - Sending oneway from: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 to target: localhost/127.0.0.1:61625 command: ConnectionInfo {commandId = 1, responseRequired = true, connectionId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-1:1, clientId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-0:1, clientIp = null, userName = aymenmhidhi, password = *****, brokerPath = null, brokerMasterConnector = false, manageable = true, clientMaster = true, faultTolerant = false, failoverReconnect = false}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG DefaultReplayBuffer:47 - Adding command ID: 1 to replay buffer: org.apache.activemq.transport.reliable.DefaultReplayBuffer@7e3e2cff object: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=129 lim=4096 cap=4096]
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:242 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 sending datagram: 1 to: localhost/127.0.0.1:61625
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:110 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 received from: Endpoint[name:/127.0.0.1:49258] about to process: Response {commandId = 1, responseRequired = false, correlationId = 1}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:60 - RECEIVED: Response {commandId = 1, responseRequired = false, correlationId = 1}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:110 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 received from: Endpoint[name:/127.0.0.1:49258] about to process: ConnectionControl {commandId = 2, responseRequired = false, suspend = false, resume = false, close = false, exit = false, faultTolerant = false, connectedBrokers = , reconnectTo = , token = null, rebalanceConnection = false}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:60 - RECEIVED: ConnectionControl {commandId = 2, responseRequired = false, suspend = false, resume = false, close = false, exit = false, faultTolerant = false, connectedBrokers = , reconnectTo = , token = null, rebalanceConnection = false}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:110 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 received from: Endpoint[name:/127.0.0.1:49258] about to process: BrokerInfo {commandId = 3, responseRequired = false, brokerId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57133-1445011516433-0:1, brokerURL = tcp://aymenmhidhi-PC:61616, slaveBroker = false, masterBroker = false, faultTolerantConfiguration = false, networkConnection = false, duplexConnection = false, peerBrokerInfos = null, brokerName = localhost, connectionId = 0, brokerUploadUrl = null, networkProperties = null}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:60 - RECEIVED: BrokerInfo {commandId = 3, responseRequired = false, brokerId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57133-1445011516433-0:1, brokerURL = tcp://aymenmhidhi-PC:61616, slaveBroker = false, masterBroker = false, faultTolerantConfiguration = false, networkConnection = false, duplexConnection = false, peerBrokerInfos = null, brokerName = localhost, connectionId = 0, brokerUploadUrl = null, networkProperties = null}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:55 - SENDING: ConsumerInfo {commandId = 2, responseRequired = true, consumerId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-1:1:-1:1, destination = ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic, prefetchSize = 1000, maximumPendingMessageLimit = 0, browser = false, dispatchAsync = true, selector = null, clientId = null, subscriptionName = null, noLocal = true, exclusive = false, retroactive = false, priority = 0, brokerPath = null, optimizedAcknowledge = false, noRangeAcks = false, additionalPredicate = null}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG UdpTransport:124 - Sending oneway from: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 to target: /127.0.0.1:49258 command: ConsumerInfo {commandId = 2, responseRequired = true, consumerId = ID:aymenmhidhi-PC-57832-1445013042216-1:1:-1:1, destination = ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempQueue,ActiveMQ.Advisory.TempTopic, prefetchSize = 1000, maximumPendingMessageLimit = 0, browser = false, dispatchAsync = true, selector = null, clientId = null, subscriptionName = null, noLocal = true, exclusive = false, retroactive = false, priority = 0, brokerPath = null, optimizedAcknowledge = false, noRangeAcks = false, additionalPredicate = null}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG DefaultReplayBuffer:47 - Adding command ID: 2 to replay buffer: org.apache.activemq.transport.reliable.DefaultReplayBuffer@7e3e2cff object: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=155 lim=4096 cap=4096]
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:242 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 sending datagram: 2 to: /127.0.0.1:49258
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG CommandDatagramChannel:110 - Channel: udp://localhost:61625?trace=true@49257 received from: Endpoint[name:/127.0.0.1:49258] about to process: Response {commandId = 4, responseRequired = false, correlationId = 2}
2015-10-16 18:30:42 DEBUG Connection:1:60 - RECEIVED: Response {commandId = 4, responseRequired = false, correlationId = 2}

brokerurl 
brokerUrlUDP=udp://localhost:61625?trace=true

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code, no one can read this question and help you:)

Answer (score 0):

```
package eu.dedalus.x1v1.arr.arrReceiver;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class ActiveMQQueuListener {
    private static final Logger log = Logger
            .getLogger(ActiveMQQueuListener.class.getName());
    private String brokerUrlTLS;
    private String brokerUrlUDP;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private ArrListener listener;
    private String queueName;
    private String protocol;
    private String keyStore;
    private String trustStore;
    private String keyStorePassword;
    private String trustStorePassword;
    private boolean exit = false;
    private QueueConnection connection = null;
    private QueueSession session = null;
    private ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactoryUDP;
    private ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactoryTLS;
    private MessageConsumer consumer;
    private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;
    private TransportConnector connector;

    public void startReceiving() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("------Start receiving---------");

        try {
            switch (protocol) {
            case "UDP":
                connectionFactoryUDP = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
                        brokerUrlUDP);
                connection = connectionFactoryUDP.createQueueConnection(
                        username, password);

                break;
            case "TLS":

                connectionFactoryTLS = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory();
                // create connection

                connectionFactoryTLS.setBrokerURL(brokerUrlTLS);
                connectionFactoryTLS.setTrustStore(trustStore);
                connectionFactoryTLS.setTrustStorePassword(trustStorePassword);
                connectionFactoryTLS.setKeyStore(keyStore);
                connectionFactoryTLS.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
                connection = connectionFactoryTLS.createQueueConnection(
                        username, password);

                break;
            }

            // ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new
            // ActiveMQConnectionFactory(this.username, this.password,
            // "tcp://localhost:61616");
            // create connection

            // start

            connection.start();

            // create session

            // create queue (it will create if queue doesn't exist)

            // create listener

            MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMessage(Message message) {

                    // only text type message
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        TextMessage txt = (TextMessage) message;
                        try {
                            System.out
                                    .println("Message received =---_________--"
                                            + txt.getText());
                        } catch (JMSException e) {
                            System.out.println("error retrieving message");
                            System.exit(1);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };

            session = connection.createQueueSession(false,
                    Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queueName);
            QueueReceiver consumer = session.createReceiver(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
            System.in.read();
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("-----------closed----------");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while sending message to the queue"
                    + e);
            throw e;
        }

    }

    public void setListener(ArrListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public ArrListener getListener() {
        return listener;
    }

    public static Logger getLog() {
        return log;
    }

    public String getQueueName() {
        return queueName;
    }

    public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }

    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public String getKeyStore() {
        return keyStore;
    }

    public void setKeyStore(String keyStore) {
        this.keyStore = keyStore;
    }

    public String getTrustStore() {
        return trustStore;
    }

    public void setTrustStore(String trustStore) {
        this.trustStore = trustStore;
    }

    public String getKeyStorePassword() {
        return keyStorePassword;
    }

    public void setKeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword) {
        this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
    }

    public String getTrustStorePassword() {
        return trustStorePassword;
    }

    public void setTrustStorePassword(String trustStorePassword) {
        this.trustStorePassword = trustStorePassword;
    }

    public String getBrokerUrlTLS() {
        return brokerUrlTLS;
    }

    public void setBrokerUrlTLS(String brokerUrlTLS) {
        this.brokerUrlTLS = brokerUrlTLS;
    }

    public String getBrokerUrlUDP() {
        return brokerUrlUDP;
    }

    public void setBrokerUrlUDP(String brokerUrlUDP) {
        this.brokerUrlUDP = brokerUrlUDP;
    }

    public void exitMethod() {
        System.exit(1);
        try {
            consumer.close();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
            System.out.println("-----------closed----------");

        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean isExit() {
        return exit;
    }

    public void setExit(boolean exit) {

        this.exit = exit;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory getConnectionFactoryUDP() {
        return connectionFactoryUDP;
    }

    public void setConnectionFactoryUDP(
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactoryUDP) {
        this.connectionFactoryUDP = connectionFactoryUDP;
    }

    public ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory getConnectionFactoryTLS() {
        return connectionFactoryTLS;
    }

    public void setConnectionFactoryTLS(
            ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactoryTLS) {
        this.connectionFactoryTLS = connectionFactoryTLS;
    }

}
```